# C# Run PowerShell code on specific version 3.0 instead of 2.0

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to run PowerShell from a C# binary. It works without a problem if the target framework is .Net4  or higher.
But it does not work when the target framework is set to 3.0. When I output the version of PowerShell, I just get 2.0 and an Error which does not support the needed commands.

For example, if I run the following code with target framework 3.0:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

using System.Management.Automation;


namespace dotNetCMD
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string psCommand = "";
            string psOutFile = "dotNetCMD.txt";

            string psResult = "";
            string psError = "";

            // Command = "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion";
            psCommand = "Get-WinSystemLocale";

            try
            {
                PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

                // ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("WebAdministration");
                ps.AddScript(psCommand);
                Collection<PSObject> psObject = ps.Invoke();

                foreach (PSObject obj in psObject)
                {
                    if (obj.BaseObject is XmlNode)
                    {
                        psResult += (obj.BaseObject as XmlNode).InnerText;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        psResult += obj.BaseObject.ToString();
                    }

                    if (psObject.Count > 1)
                    {
                        psResult += " - ";
                    }
                }

                foreach (ErrorRecord err in ps.Streams.Error)
                {
                    psError += err.ToString();
                    if (psObject.Count > 0)
                    {
                        psError += " - ";
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                psError = ex.Message;
            }

            // if error
            if (psError.Length > 1)
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(psOutFile.Substring(0, psOutFile.Length - 4) + ".error.txt");
                sw.WriteLine(psError);
                sw.Close();

                // return 1;
                //Environment.Exit(1);
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + psError);

            }
            else
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(psOutFile);
                sw.WriteLine(psResult);
                sw.Close();

                //return 0;
                //Environment.Exit(0);
                Console.WriteLine("INFO: " + psError);
            }

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
The term 'Get-WinSystemLocale' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: Neither .NET 2.0 or 3.0 are supported, and have been deprecated for some time. .NET 4.0 is similarly deprecated. If PowerShell requires more modern APIs to function, you will need to use the minimum version of .NET that PowerShell itself supports.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is about .NET FX versions? And not the fact that `Get-WinSystemLocale` first ships with Windows Server 2012, so it doesn't work on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: I know those frameworks are no longer in use but the main product is still supported on Server 2012.
`Get-WinSystemLocale` was just test command. To be precise, I will need all the IIS management commands like `Get-WebBinding`, `Get-WebAppDomain`, etc...